# Significance of Wronskian appearing in particle flux

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering, probability

When we derive the expression for particle flux/probability current, we find that it is directly proportional to the Wronskian of $\psi$ and its conjugate and deduce that it is constant when particle current is constant.

Is it just a coincidence that the Wronskian shows up, or does the have some noteworthy implications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to one dimension, as the identification only holds for one space dimension, so you might well call it a coincidence,
$$
j={\hbar\over 2mi}(\psi^*\partial_x \psi -\psi \partial_x \psi^*), \\
\partial_t \rho + \partial_x j =0  ~~~~\leadsto ~~~ v(x) = j/\rho    ~~. 
$$

Vanishing Wronskian suggests (not quite dictates) that $\psi^*$ is linearly dependent on $\psi$, i.e. $\partial_x (\ln (\psi^*/\psi))=0$; so they may only differ by a constant phase, absorbable, hence the wave function is basically real, and the probability density constant over time. This is what you get in stationary systems.

A constant current *J* also indicates, for $\psi\equiv \sqrt{\rho} ~ e^{is(x)}$, a special velocity
$$
J={\hbar\rho \over m} \partial_x s,  
  ~~~~\leadsto ~~~  \psi\equiv \sqrt{\rho} ~~e^{i(\alpha+ \int^x \!dx' ~ Jm/\hbar \rho(x') ) }
$$
so *ρ* is again time independent, even though *ψ* is genuinely complex.